# Problem Serializing Spring batch Kafka ChunkRequest

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am writing a sample Spring batch Kafka integration, with Remote Chunking.
At first a master read some sample record (Item.java) in some Chunks. Then send this chunks to a (Spring Integration) channel and a Kafka producer send this Chunks to a Kafka topic.
The problem is KafkaTemplate cant serialize the ChenkRequest.

if I use :

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

then this error raise:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Can't convert value of class org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer specified in value.serializer
```

and if I write a custom serializer like:

```java
public class CustomSerializer implements Serializer<ChunkRequest<Item>> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, ChunkRequest<Item> data) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Serializing...");
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when serializing MessageDto to byte[]");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }
}
```

and this config:

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=com.example.myremotechunking.batch.CustomSerializer
```

this error would raise:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]
```

So, what is the problem!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org:spring-projects org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest` is not JSON-compatible. Consider to write a `Serializer<ChunkRequest<Item>>` which would serialize using standard Java serialization feature. You may use a `org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serializeToByteArray()` from Spring as a delegate.

Probably you would need a similar deserialzier on the other side...

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Artem.
that worked!
I wrote a customer serializer:

```java
public class CustomSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        try {
            return new DefaultSerializer().serializeToByteArray(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SerializationException("Error when serializing MessageDto to byte[]");
        }
    }
}
```

with config:

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=com.example.myremotechunking.batch.CustomSerializer
```

and a custom deserializer:

```java
public class CustomDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            return new DefaultDeserializer().deserialize(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with config:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=com.example.myremotechunking.batch.CustomDeserializer
```